# ¿Como podría validar en mi metodo vue que solo acepte archivos jpg?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

deseo validar que se carger solo imagenes y evitar que cargen otro tipo de archivos, de antemano gracias quien me puedo ayudar.

//formulario

[image: parte donde selecciono imagen]

//parte de mi vista

```
<div class="col-3">
                        <div class="col-12">

                            <form>
                            <div >
                                <label class="file-upload btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right" style="width: 30px;">
                                    ... <input type="file" @change="onFileChange" accept=".jpg"/>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            </form>

                        </div> 
                        <div>
                           <img :src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ mantenimientos.l_logo" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 170px; height: 113px;"> 
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

//vuejs metodo para seleccionar e cargar imagen

```
methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
        return;
          this.createImage(files[0]);  
    },
    createImage(file) {
        var image = new Image();
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.mantenimientos.l_logo = ((e.target.result).split(","))[1];
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes verificar el `type` del archivo.

```
methods: {
onFileChange(e) {
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length && !(files[0].type == 'image/png' || files[0].type == 'image/jpg' ...))
        return;
      this.createImage(files[0]);  
},
createImage(file) {
    var image = new Image();
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.mantenimientos.l_logo = ((e.target.result).split(","))[1];
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```